# Align p- chart centrally inside p-panel

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am trying to centrally align  p-chart inside a p-panel. However I'm unable to figure out the right css to do so. Please help.

This is my template code:

```
   <p-panel header="Charts">
       <p-chart type="bar" height="150px" width="50vw" [data]="barChartData" style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;">
      </p-chart>
   </p-panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.Posting the answer.Adding the below css aligns the chart centrally-

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```